# Extract frames using Matlab mmreader

Tags: matlab, video-processing

I'm extracting frames from an avi file whose frame rate is 49.979fps. I tried mmreader in matlab, but all the extracted frames look like this:
[image]

This is so wired! It looks like the frame is cuted into several horizontal layers, and then these layers are rotated and stretched. Does anybody know how to fix this? THX!!!

Answer (score 0):

I've figured it out myself. It's because of the codec. Just use mmread toolbox instead.